# rotate text by using LESS

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to rotate text by using LESS

Simply, I try the following code but it does not work.

```
.my-class {
    color: #ff0000;
    .rotate(90);
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2750/

Comment: Is LESS *allowed* as "plain CSS" these days? Or is it some jsfiddle magic to run the transformation? - I always thought LESS required the use of a "CSS compiler" to turn it into real CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try adding a unit? (or *an unit Mr president*?)

```
.rotate(90deg)
```

See [MDN about CSS3 transform and rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform#rotate) for more information. That's what LESS.js or lessphp will output

Answer (score 6):

To make css rotation work on all browsers including ie7 through ie10 using LESS, I am using a mixin like this:

```
.rotate(@deg: 90) {
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(@deg * 1deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(@deg * 1deg);
    /* IE10+ */
    transform: rotate(@deg * 1deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(@deg * 1deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    @IEdeg: round(@deg / 90, 0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=@IEdeg);
}

#divToRotate {
   .rotate(270);
}
```

But you won't be able to run this in js fiddle since this will need to be compiled by lessc compiler or using the less js parser.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write it in plain CSS, and it will work in LESS: `transform: rotate(90deg);`.

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer. but to me it does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2751/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
.box_rotate {
 -moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
   -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
         filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);  /* IE6,IE7 */
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
     }
```

Check this link:- http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the LESS library: [LESS Elements](http://lesselements.com/) it has a mixin for rotate which seems to work in lots of browsers:

> .rotation(15deg); Rotates the item by a number of degrees clockwise.